# Change this code to show a shelf on all lines

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

i am using nopcommerce 2.80 source

I have added some code to my website that displays a shelf under each row of 4 products, the problem i am now facing is that when it comes to the last row where only 2 or 3 products are available no shelf displays,

i have inserted this code into the categoryTemplateProductsInGridsOrLines.cshtml

```
 <div class="product-grid">
            @{                   
                int i = 0;                   
             }
           @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
           {              
               <div class="item-box">
                   @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", product)
               </div>
               i++;  
               double num = (double)i / 4;
               if (System.Math.Ceiling(num) == num && System.Math.Floor(num) == num)
               {
                    <div id="shelf"></div>                                           
               }                                        
            }
        </div>
```

how would i change this so that the shelf appears on all rows of products with no mininum number limit but a max number limit of 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another shelf after the foreach loop if the count % 4 != 0:

```
<div class="product-grid">
        @{                   
            int i = 0;                   
         }
       @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
       {              
           <div class="item-box">
               @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", product)
           </div>
           i++;  
           double num = (double)i / 4;
           if (System.Math.Ceiling(num) == num && System.Math.Floor(num) == num)
           {
                <div id="shelf"></div>                                           
           }                                        
        }

        @{
            if(Model.Products.Count % 4 != 0)
            {
                <div id="shelf"></div>
            }   
        }
    </div>
```